# Query Wordpress Posts before/after a specific datetime

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need a little help, is it possible to query Wordpress posts before or after a specific date time?

The Wordpress codex says for before and after it accepts an array of year, month an day. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

But what if I want to get all posts for a given date and time e.g. before 2018-12-07 and 08:12:00 ?

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You can also pass a string, so '2018-12-07 08:12' will work just fine ([source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/date.php#L886)).

Comment: @msg thanks a lot! works!